# What could be raising this "RuntimeError: Trying to resize storage that is not resizable"?

Tags: amazon-ec2, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

Has anyone ever experienced the error above? Any idea what could be raising it?

I get the error only on a specific dataset and it is thrown as batch 19 is loaded, always 19. Even though the data was split randomly.

The dataset is composed of 5 second audio .wav files that I transform into a spectrogram upon fetch.

```
Starting training for 1000 epoch(s)
Epoch 1/1000
 26%|█████████████████████▉                                                             | 19/72 [00:04<00:13,  3.86it/s, loss=33.745]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 202, in <module>
    train_and_evaluate(model, train_dl, test_dl, optimizer, cost, params, args.model_dir, args.experiment_name, args.restore_file)
  File "train.py", line 129, in train_and_evaluate
    train(model, optimizer, loss_fn, train_dataloader, params, epoch, writer)
  File "train.py", line 52, in train
    for i, (train_batch, current_rpm, next_rpm, next_pr) in enumerate(dataloader):
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/SFB/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 628, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/SFB/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 1333, in _next_data
    return self._process_data(data)
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/SFB/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 1359, in _process_data
    data.reraise()
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/SFB/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/_utils.py", line 543, in reraise
    raise exception
RuntimeError: Caught RuntimeError in DataLoader worker process 3.
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/SFB/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/worker.py", line 302, in _worker_loop
    data = fetcher.fetch(index)
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/SFB/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 61, in fetch
    return self.collate_fn(data)
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/SFB/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 265, in default_collate
    return collate(batch, collate_fn_map=default_collate_fn_map)
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/SFB/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 143, in collate
    return [collate(samples, collate_fn_map=collate_fn_map) for samples in transposed]  # Backwards compatibility.
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/SFB/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 143, in <listcomp>
    return [collate(samples, collate_fn_map=collate_fn_map) for samples in transposed]  # Backwards compatibility.
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/SFB/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 120, in collate
    return collate_fn_map[elem_type](batch, collate_fn_map=collate_fn_map)
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/SFB/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 162, in collate_tensor_fn
    out = elem.new(storage).resize_(len(batch), *list(elem.size()))
RuntimeError: Trying to resize storage that is not resizable
```

I've tried a different dataset of 2 second .wav recordings and it works fine.

Comment: This should be due to a mismatch in the size of the input.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this error while I was developing a computer vision project for an embedded system. The goal of the project was to compare two images using a neural network, that has to state if such images were similar or not. In order to reduce the size of the network, I was not feeding the network with the whole image, but with a feature vector obtained applying the ORB algorithm.

The problem was that I was obtaining a vector with different size from each image (different keypoints).
The default collate_fn of the Dataloader object does not tollerate this.
I had two solutions:

1. Manually add a sort of padding in such a way that all the feature vectors in the current batch have the same size; or
2. Write a custom collate_fn capable of dealing with batch elements of different size.

I followed the first solution and it worked for me: I write a custom Dataset object that resized and padded each feature vector to a fixed size (in the `__getitem__` method).

Maybe, in your case, you should need a custom collate_fn.

I suggest you to read:

- official documentation of the [Dataloader class](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader)
- [blog article](https://plainenglish.io/blog/understanding-collate-fn-in-pytorch-f9d1742647d3) which shows a NLP use case, where a custom collate_fn is very useful